# Disable Sound on NSButton

Tags: xcode, cocoa, audio, xib, nsbutton

In my xib I have defined that some of my NSButtons have a sound file that should play whenever the button is clicked. I'd like to offer my users the option to disable sound effects. Is there any way to disable the sound file that is played by the NSButtons other than just iterating over every button in my view and [button setSound:nil]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSSound instance method

```
- (void)setVolume:(float)volume
```

The volume range is between 0.0 and 1.0.
This method does not affect the systemwide volume.